# Django add extra field to a ModelForm generated from a Model

Tags: django, japplet, django-forms

I have to generate a FormSet from a model but I need to insert an "extra value" in to every form.

Specifically, I have a JApplet that generates some Markers and Paths on a image, and POST it on the server.

In my model lines are composed from two Markers. But when I POST it, because I'm using the id generated from the JApplet and not from the database, I will not know from which Markers a Path will be composed.

So I thought to insert a "temporary id" on the Marker on the form, and do the correct arrangements in the view before saving the Path.

I thought about defining a custom form for the markers, but it not seems to be very DRY, and I don't want to came back to this if I change the Marker model.

Here is the form:

```
  class PointForm(forms.ModelForm):
    temp_id = forms.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
            model = Point

    def clean(self):
            if any(self.errors):
                    # Don't bother validating the formset unless each form is valid on its own
                    return

            ingresso = self.cleaned_data['ingresso']
            ascensore = self.cleaned_data['ascensore']
            scala = self.cleaned_data['scala']

            if (ingresso and ascensore) or (ingresso and scala) or (ascensore and scala):
                    raise forms.ValidationError("A stair cannot be a elevator or an access!!!") 
            return self

    def save(commit=True):
    # do something with self.cleaned_data['temp_id']
            super(PointForm).save(commit=commit)
```

And the model:

```
  class Point(models.Model):

    RFID = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    x = models.IntegerField()
    y = models.IntegerField()

    piano = models.ForeignKey(Floor)

    ingresso = models.BooleanField()
```

The error:

```
  ViewDoesNotExist at /admin/
  Could not import buildings.views.getFloors. View does not exist in module buildings.views.
  Request Method:   GET
  Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
  Django Version:   1.4.1
  Exception Type:   ViewDoesNotExist
  Exception Value:  
  Could not import buildings.views.getFloors. View does not exist in module buildings.views.
  Exception Location:   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in get_callable, line 101
```

The error is generated when I try to load the admin page, this page has no references at all with the form.

**SOLUTION FOR EXCEPTION**

Ok, I'll write here how to find out why Django was doing such a strange thing.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393257/viewdoesnotexist-error) it's a correct way to find out what is the problem.

The exception was thrown because I forgot to add `forms.py` to the `from django import forms`.

Comment: And, if I remove _getFloors_ from _url.py_ it calls an error of _missing view_ on the next url in _url.py_...
Is this a bug?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can add a field to a ModelForm. Unless you add a field named temp_id to your model you do not need to change this form when you change you model.

**Example (with a model named Point):**

```
class PointForm (forms.ModelForm):
    temp_id = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Point

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # do something with self.cleaned_data['temp_id']
        return super(PointForm, self).save(commit=commit)
```

**UPDATE:** Forgot self in def save() and changed modelname to Point

Comment: I have tried this approach before @relekang, but I get a 

_Could not import buildings.views.getFloors. View does not exist in module buildings.views._

When I remove the line _temp_id = forms.IntegerField()_ all works well...

Comment: Looks like you are having problems with circular imports.

Comment: Somehow doing this resulted in my `clean` method not being run and I can't figure out why. UGH.

Answer (score 5):

To follow up relekang's answer, I had to be reminded to also [return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117346/save-custom-field-in-django-modelform) the last line as shown, so that the object's get_absolute_url() method could be automatically called on submission of the form:

```
return super(PointForm, self).save(commit=commit)
```