# Save custom field in Django ModelForm

Tags: django, modelform

I am having trouble saving a custom field in a ModelForm. The field in question is a ModelChoiceField.

I have added a `save()` method as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550515/django-add-extra-field-to-a-modelform-generated-from-a-model) question. However, when I use it I get an error:

> ImproperlyConfigured 
>   No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.

When I remove my custom `save()` method it works ok but doesn't save the custom field. What am I missing?

```
class NewStoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Story
        fields = ['title', 'story_text']

    #custom field
    about = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None)

    #initialise custom field
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewStoryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['about'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Experience.objects.filter(user=user))

    #save custom field
    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.instance.about  = self.cleaned_data['about']
        super(NewStoryForm, self).save(commit=commit)

class NewStoryView(CreateView):
    form_class = NewStoryForm
    template_name = 'story/story_form.html'

    #Send user to NewStoryForm to initialise custom field
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(NewStoryView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs

    #save author as current user
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super(NewStoryView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should **return** the saved object from the `save()` method:

```
return super(NewStoryForm, self).save(commit=commit)
```